# How to remove drive encryption?

Tags: encryption, windows-8

I have a new Win8 laptop that has an encrypted SSD. I can't install Ubuntu until I remove the encryption. Can I do this without involving the manufacturer and voiding my warranty?

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the type of disk encryption that is used on the laptop. If the laptop is using BitLocker full disk encryption then you can turn it off by following the directions at: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/using-bitlocker-drive-encryption . If you are using some other full disk encryption then you will need to post more details.

Comment: I don't have bitlocker -- I don't have Win8 pro. But -- in the system properties, it shows I have drive protection turned on for C: -- if I disable it, it will delete my restore points (not too worried about it - I have a recovery drive) -- would this do it?

Comment: I don't know. I am not a Windows 8 expert but if you are running Windows 8 and not Windows 8 Pro or Windows 8 Enterprise it is unlikely that your laptop supports bitlocker. If you have a recovery drive and you a comfortable recovering Windows 8 should something go wrong then you can try it. However if you are using drive encryption software other than Bitlocker than it likely wouldn't do anything unless OEMs have the ability to turn on Bitlocker for Windows 8.